# How to run multiple python scripts when raspberry boots using /etc/rc.local

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, debian

I have 3 scripts that I would like to run simultaneously when my raspberry boots up.

All 3 scripts will stay running while the raspberry stays awake, but on /etc/rc.local when i run my first script, the file stay on this command line and does not run the other ones.

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/script1.py <- stay here
sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/script2.py <- does not execute
sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/script3.py <- does not execute
```

Is there is another way to execute all scripts simultaneously when my raspberry boots up?

P.S.: All scripts use a multi thread, so run all of them on the same terminal will decrease more the performance of my rasp.
I'm using Raspibian GNU/linux 10 (buster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
python3 /home/pi/Documents/script1.py &
python3 /home/pi/Documents/script2.py &
python3 /home/pi/Documents/script3.py
```

Comment: There's no need for `sudo`, this scrpt already runs as `root`.